# Laravel Routes - Possible to reuse ajax route call from one form on different form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-7

I have an existing route I created to perform an ajax call for a chained select:

```
Route::get('add/{id}','AddAssetController@getModel');
```

The above queries the db for models belonging to each manufacturer.

The url part of the ajax call (man_ID is the id of the manufacturer from the select):

```
url: 'add/' + man_ID,
```

The above works perfectly on the main form where I am using it. However, I've found that I need this chained select on more than one form. Is there a way to be able to use the same route for two different pages? I've tried calling it from a different page and in the console, I'm getting a 404 error.

Am I missing something? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling the script from the differently nested pages, thus `add/` is ultimately calling different path.
I would strongly advise you name your routes, and generate links like that:

```php
Route::get('add/{id}','AddAssetController@getModel')->name('get-model');
```

and in your blade file

```js
url: '{{route('get-model', ['id' => $id])}}',
```

if you still set on using paths to call your script, use them *relative to your root*:

```js
url: '/add/' + man_ID,
```

Comment: Nice answer, I would like to add one thing. In case if you want to use a javascript variable, call the route like this.


`url: "{{ route('get-model','/') }}" + '/' + man_ID`

Comment: @Ashraf789 This will not work, In laravel 7 you have to specify correct parameter for routes. Generating this url will throw the error, that required parameter [id] is not set

Comment: Well, I am currently working with **Laravel Framework 7.14.1** and this technique is working fine for me. But I will be glad if I could learn any new technique. 

Could you share any new technique to access the javascript variable with route calls?
Thanks.

Comment: @Ashraf789, you are right, this hack is working, you don't even need to include the slash `{{ route('get-model','') }}` seems to be sufficient.

Comment: nice. Thank you.

Comment: @Ashraf789 Referring to your question, I generally try to avoid using parameterized routes in my js (unless I really want inject a dependency). Otherwise I would use query params or pass entire url as a parameter for my ajax function...